# Fill XY with images of all different sizes, reduce white space and no cutoffs

Tags: image, algorithm, fill

Basically, I need to be able to print a number of images, and if those images are being printed on an 11x7 (example), I need to fit them so I get the minimum space used with all the images on them.

Example:

[image]

I'm not entirely sure how I would proceed with this as everything I can think of comes up with cut-off images, or with all images having to be the same size, or potential for overlapping images.

How do I programmatically do this?

Comment: You could maybe have a little look at my answer below for some ideas... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099955/photoshop-script-layout-images-like-flickr/30625536#30625536

Comment: Close to what I was looking for, but I want the height and the width to be dynamic, not just one or the other. The additional area lost will be very costly.

Comment: Are you restricted to guillotine cuts (which must cut the full width of your material), or can you cut part way across then change direction in the middle of the cut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a known hard problem called the two-dimensional cutting stock problem. See for example http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.3.9465&rep=rep1&type=pdf, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem, and http://www2.inf.uos.de/papers_html/or_94/node3.html - or just search on these terms.