# ImageMagick create a composite grid from N images

Tags: imagemagick

How would I create a composite/grid(i'm not sure the legit terminology) from a group of differently sized images.

Is there a *tried and true* method for this?

For example:

```
1. [1,2]
2. [1,2,3]
3. [[1,2],[3,4]] 
4. [[1,2,3], [4,5]] (here the images on the 2nd row would have to be wider than images on the first row. 
5. [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
6. [[1,2,3],[4,5], [6,7]] here rows 2 and 3 would have to be wider than the top row.
# and so on...
```

is my expectation silly? is there another way to make a decent looking grid of N images?

Comment: Kinda depends how you define *"decent"*!

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes I think my expectation would mean a grid that can be consistently reproduced with similar sizes each time.

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick's `montage` will do a pretty reasonable job with:

```
montage image1.png ... imageN.jpg -geometry +10+10 montage.gif
```

If you know you want 3 columns, you can add `-tile 3x` to force that. Likewise `-tile x4` if you want 4 rows.

Beyond that, you can get image dimensions and lay them out any way you want if you have some aesthetics that appeal to your sense of order. I did one ages ago... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30625536/2836621).