# How do I merge multiple images into one with exact positions and sizes to create a sprite sheet with graphicsmagick?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to use graphicmagick (or imagesmagick) to combine multiples images into one single image all with various dimensions and sizes. Ideally, it would be an image like this: [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2SWc.jpg)

I've been scouring the forums and googles for days to figure out how to exactly accomplish that but I'm quite new at image manipulation and am now at a loss as to how to accomplish this in nodejs.

In the attached image, I'd have say 15 different images that would need to be merged into one.

Comment: This may help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/30625536/2836621

Comment: Thanks, helps some but not much. Uses bash and I actually don't see anywhere where they used graphics/imagemagick

Comment: See Imagemagick montage command at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/ You can avoid the labels and adjust the spacing, if you want, so that it looks similar to your example. However, each image will be in its own cell (tile).

Comment: Thanks @fmw42.  I thought the montage method maybe along with the geometry flag was what I needed. I couldn't find/work through and good examples though. Any code examples or basic snippets to get it started?

Answer (score 2):

Here are 3 examples using ImageMagick and montage. You use the -geometry +X+Y to set the spacing and -tile XxY to set the number of columns and rows, respectively.

Input images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
montage shading.gif present.gif medical.gif balloon.gif -tile 4x1 -geometry +10+10 montage1.jpg
```

[image]

```
montage shading.gif present.gif medical.gif balloon.gif -tile 2x2 -geometry +10+10 montage2.jpg
```

[image]

```
montage shading.gif present.gif medical.gif -tile 2x2 -geometry +10+10 montage3.jpg
```

[image]

Let me know if you need more information.

If you have all the files in one directory and in alphabetic order you want them presented according to your -tile argument, then you can change directories to the directory and do

montage * -geometry +10+10 -tile XxY result

You can also change the background color, add labels and/or frames. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/

What is your ImageMagick version? If IM 6, then the above should work. Windows users may need to use path2\convert.exe where path2 is the path to imagemagick convert (as opposed to Windows convert); or rename ImageMagick convert. If ImageMagick 7, then use "magick montage" rather than "montage".

Comment: Thanks alot. This is very helpful. I think my biggest problem is I just can't seem to figure out how to implement this in nodejs. I need to do the manipulations as a part of an application I'm building. I've defaulted to accomplish that using this gm wrapper but hopefully I can get it done with your examples ( http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html)

Comment: Sorry, I do not know anything about nodes

Comment: If you need the sprites to be placed exactly and not in regularly spaced rows and columns, then you will need to write a script loop over each image that uses convert background sprite -geometry +X+Y compose over -composite background to place each sprite a the desired X,Y locations onto the background which has to be updated with the same name after each composite.

Comment: Finally solved what I wanted to accomplish using node-canvas.  https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas